# How to use the for loop in fetching Id's from a rows in a table to be used by a procedure in PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

**This is my code below I get this error(Error at line 24/8: ORA-06550: line 20, column 12:PLS-00201: identifier 'A.ID' must be declared) as shown in the image below when I try running the code. Please how can I write the plsql code properly(using for loop) to fetch each row ID and pass them to the procedure?**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE
   p_id     number(30);
   p_status varchar(20);

BEGIN



for c in (
 SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.STATUS

  INTO
     p_id,
     p_status
  from USER_COMMISSIONS a,
  order_line b where a.order_line_id=b.id and a.status= 'unconfirmed'
   
         )

         LOOP
         begin
    
   p_id := a.ID;
   p_status := a.STATUS;


   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;

end;

-- update pstk_payload set status = 'done' where id = pyld_id;

dbms_output.put_line(p_id); 

-- PSTK_PAYMENT_PACKAGE.add_payment(p_amt, p_user_id, p_reference, p_name, p_narration, p_payment_date, p_net_amt, p_payment_type_id, p_transaction_type_id, p_payment_id, p_status);
  
    END LOOP;
end;

END;
```

Comment: The loop record is called `c`, not `a`. Also, there's no `into` keyword in the syntax for cursor FOR loops, although the compiler may ignore it rather than complain.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamRobertson, this solved it. I replaced it with 'a'

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to declare, actually - everything you need (at least, in code you posted and that's not commented) is contained in cursor itself.

As William commented, you need to reference columns with the cursor name (not tables that are their source).

Also, no need for any exception handler; cursor certainly won't return `no_data_found`; if its `select` doesn't return anything the only "consequence" will be that none of commands within the loop will be executed.

If you're joining tables, then use `JOIN`; leave `where` clause for conditions (if any).

Therefore:

```
begin
  for c in (select a.id,
                   a.status
            from user_commissions a join order_line b on a.order_line_id = b.id 
            where a.status= 'unconfirmed'
           )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.id ||', '|| c.status);    
  end loop;
end;
```